# Unit testing a grails plugin which uses another plugin

Tags: grails

I am writing a Grails plugin for my project which uses a another grails plugin, written by another group in the organization. I want to unit test my grails plugin code, but it uses the this other plugin, and when I unit test, my code fails because the other plugin is not loaded.

How do I load this other plugin before my unit tests are run?

Comment: How do you have the other group's plugin installed?

Comment: They are direct references using "grails.plugin.location" property.

Comment: That should be able to pickup everything from a plugin.  Have you tried doing a `grails clean`?  I know that's not a great suggestion but sometimes it seems to help clean up dependency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I could get the same done with integration tests. So wrote integration test instead of unit tests.